eBPF file getting stripped in %install section
I'm packaging an application including an eBPF program. I currently have the following in the %install section of my spec file:
%install
...
cp program-ebpf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/program/
...

rpmbuild fails with /usr/bin/strip: Unable to recognize the format of the input file .... The file is of course not a regular binary as it's eBPF bytecode.
Question: How do I copy this file into my RPM without triggering strip? This only seems to happen on newer versions of rpmbuild? Older versions don't call strip if using the cp command.

IIRC, it will only call strip on files with the executable bit set. Undo that with chmod and it should be skipped. Then if it actually needs to be executable, you can fix it in %postinstall
